# Перенаправление на https с закреплённым "индексом"

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

В htaccess прописано правило:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Таким образом все запросы отправляются index.php для обработки.

Возникла проблема. В связи с этими правилами приоритет htaccess становится выше и сервер не перенаправляет запросы с http на https

Есть подозрения, что нужно поправить строчку

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

На что-то подобное

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Но как правильно это сделать, чтобы все запросы так же перенаправлялись на index.php но по https протоколу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f 
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d 
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```